# Determine moments of inertia of a tool experimentally

Tags: dynamics, kuka

I've mounted a broom as an effector of the Kuka IIWA. I've configured a tool in the Kuka Sunrise Workbench software with approximative mass and center of gravity. However, when control is started with a light stiffness, the end effector is slightly attracted by the gravity on its own. I assume the cause is that information about dynamics of the broom are incorrect.

[image]

I'm looking for an experimental setup that would allow to measure these data about the broom, as precisely as possible:

- Center of mass (I can easily measure the center of mass along the
  stick, but how about in 3D?)
- Principal inertia axes (radians)
- Principal moments of inertia about these axes (kg * m²)

Comment: Have you learned the parallel axis theorem?  That will help your experimental computations.